# RxJava Subject and Completable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have situation in which I try to subscribe to Completable that updates my DB. I cannot control when that method is triggered but I need to know if it has ended before I try to read data from it. I was thinking to make a Hot Completable and subscribe to it and check if it has completed. Now, I don't really know if I can subscribe with a Subject to a Completable. Should I go with Observable instead?

```
fun myCompletable(): Completable {...}

myCompletable.subscribe(mySubject)

mySubject.subscribe(checkIfCompletableHasCompleteMethod())
```

Is there another way to check if my method has completed before invoking the next one in an RX chain?

```
myRepo.someMethodThatInvokesMyCompletableMethodInternally()
    .waitUntilMyCompletableMethodCompletes()
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: There is a [`CompletableSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/CompletableSubject.html) you can use. As for how to wait it, it really depends on what that someMethod returns. It could be as simple as `someMethod().andThen(mySubject).subscribe()`.

Comment: This one definitely works for me. I will try to implement with this one.